# How can I specify what <table class> I want when there are multiple duplicates in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So basically, I was using

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url='https://bn.mappersguild.com/'

headers={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
row = soup.find("table", {"class": "table table-sm table-dark table-hover col-6 col-md-3"}).get_text()
```

in order to get second list from the following which is under `<td>taiko</td>`

````
 <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-hover col-6 col-md-3">
                <thead>
                    <td>catch</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2931883" target="_blank">Ascendance</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/318565" target="_blank">Deif</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2369776" target="_blank">Greaper</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4778689" target="_blank">-Luminate</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/829284" target="_blank">Bunnrei</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/8140944" target="_blank">Dapuluous</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4879508" target="_blank">JBHyperion</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7890134" target="_blank">Jemzuu</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4915649" target="_blank">Lacrima</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3071175" target="_blank">MBomb</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5032045" target="_blank">wonjae</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1521445" target="_blank">Xinely</a></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-hover col-6 col-md-3">
                <thead>
                    <td>taiko</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/845733" target="_blank">Faputa</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/6637817" target="_blank">Nepuri</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2474015" target="_blank">Capu</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3901754" target="_blank">Cynplytholowazy</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3388410" target="_blank">eiri-</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7612550" target="_blank">frukoyurdakul</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9856910" target="_blank">Gamelan4</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9892196" target="_blank">Hoshikuz</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/6256027" target="_blank">incandescence</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/394326" target="_blank">kanpakyin</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/876419" target="_blank">Nardoxyribonucleic</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1561995" target="_blank">neonat</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7131099" target="_blank">radar</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/626907" target="_blank">Stefan</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2774767" target="_blank">tasuke912</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1421452" target="_blank">Tyistiana</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4154071" target="_blank">Volta</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4901066" target="_blank">Vulkin</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2377881" target="_blank">Yales</a></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-hover col-6 col-md-3">
                <thead>
                    <td>mania</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4815717" target="_blank">Feerum</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7138602" target="_blank">Leniane</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/6209713" target="_blank">_Kobii</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1653229" target="_blank">_Stan</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9228569" target="_blank">Amiichii</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9555243" target="_blank">Dubstek</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7439226" target="_blank">Kamuy</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4647754" target="_blank">Kawawa</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/6866022" target="_blank">Keiga</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3617111" target="_blank">PokeSky</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4610379" target="_blank">Rivals_7</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/11085809" target="_blank">Scotty</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9461160" target="_blank">UnluckyCroco</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7560872" target="_blank">Unpredictable</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9229539" target="_blank">Voxa</a></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-hover col-6 col-md-3">
                <thead>
                    <td>osu</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2202163" target="_blank">-Mo-</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3621552" target="_blank">Chaoslitz</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3193504" target="_blank">Kibbleru</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/896613" target="_blank">Lasse</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/8129817" target="_blank">Naxess</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1541323" target="_blank">Noffy</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3178418" target="_blank">pishifat</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2857314" target="_blank">Seto Kousuke</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--nat);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4945926" target="_blank">yaspo</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7150015" target="_blank">-Aqua</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3378391" target="_blank">-Keitaro</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/11119539" target="_blank">AirinCat</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/33599" target="_blank">Andrea</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4446810" target="_blank">Bibbity Bill</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/360437" target="_blank">bossandy</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4696296" target="_blank">celerih</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5226970" target="_blank">Cheri</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3626063" target="_blank">Chinochan</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/6175280" target="_blank">Cris-</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5405836" target="_blank">Crissa</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/10284894" target="_blank">Dored</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3388410" target="_blank">eiri-</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3533958" target="_blank">fieryrage</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1467715" target="_blank">Gero</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4967662" target="_blank">greenhue</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1249323" target="_blank">Hinsvar</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9155377" target="_blank">hypercyte</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5410645" target="_blank">Icekalt</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/270377" target="_blank">jonathanlfj</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2225327" target="_blank">Kaitjuh</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4236057" target="_blank">Kiryu Coco</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5312547" target="_blank">Lafayla</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3076909" target="_blank">Mafumafu</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1052994" target="_blank">Milan-</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2841009" target="_blank">Mirash</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7265097" target="_blank">Mordred</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2202645" target="_blank">Myxo</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5248582" target="_blank">Namki</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1561995" target="_blank">neonat</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7451883" target="_blank">Nevo</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4351739" target="_blank">Nikakis</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2716981" target="_blank">Nozhomi</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/10974170" target="_blank">Nuvolina</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7354729" target="_blank">Petal</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/8623835" target="_blank">Peter</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/328615" target="_blank">pimp</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/918297" target="_blank">Realazy</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1997633" target="_blank">Riana</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3056732" target="_blank">Rizen</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7777875" target="_blank">Ryuusei Aika</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9327302" target="_blank">SMOKELIND</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2140676" target="_blank">Smokeman</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/11771" target="_blank">Sonnyc</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/7601720" target="_blank">Sparhten</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9505704" target="_blank">spoes</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                        border-left: 3px solid var(--probation);
"
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/6122935" target="_blank">Stack</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/10520912" target="_blank">Teky</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5128277" target="_blank">TheKingHenry</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2072005" target="_blank">timemon</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/2652951" target="_blank">Trynna</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1314547" target="_blank">Uberzolik</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/9439796" target="_blank">Uta</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/5999631" target="_blank">Venix</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/4682629" target="_blank">Yahuri</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/3161834" target="_blank">Yugu</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="
                            border-left: 3px solid var(--bn);
                    "
                    ><a href="https://osu.ppy.sh/users/8953955" target="_blank">Zelq</a></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    ```
but bs4 keeps giving me the first list, how can I specify which duplicate I want?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the `<td>` with the text you are looking for and go to the parent table from there using `find_parent`

```
title = soup.find('td', string='taiko')
row = title.find_parent("table", {"class": "table table-sm table-dark table-hover col-6 col-md-3"}).get_text()
print(row)
```

Output:

```
taiko


Faputa
Nepuri
Capu
Cynplytholowazy
eiri-
frukoyurdakul
Gamelan4
Hoshikuz
incandescence
kanpakyin
Nardoxyribonucleic
neonat
radar
Stefan
tasuke912
Tyistiana
Volta
Vulkin
Yales
```